# If I using Ubercart and "PayPal Website Payments Pro", Can customer pay with credit card directly?

Tags: ubercart, payment-gateways

I'm not familiar with payment gateway. I'm building shopping cart selling physical product. Currently the website using: Drupal 6, Ubercart 6.x-2.4, with PayPal free account.

My client asked me to make credit card payment as simple as possible. Some customer don't know what is PayPal? When making ckeckout, they are redirected to PayPal account. After registration, they then asked to transfer from credit card to their PayPal account. They really confused and finally they refused to buy the product.

My question is: If I using Ubercart and "PayPal Website Payments Pro", Can customer pay with credit card directly without redirected to other website?

Read [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/5853/ubercart-payment-using-authorize-net-using-charge-com-reseller-but-charge-com-a) why Authorize.net is not my choice

Answer (score 2):

yes. With Paypal Pro, users remain on your site and the transaction is completed underneath by Paypal. There is no visible relationship between the two for the end user.